# Possible loss of good content due to account deletion

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-accounts

Yesterday I noticed (on Stack Overlow) answer posted by user called Community and having the [exact same avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAaeL.png) as the [community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). This was too much in my opinion, so I flagged [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17424823/447356) asking to change either the display name or the picture.

I did not expect the real Community user to take such revenge and nuke the whole account:

> [image]

That post looks legit and I remember seeing some other posts which were all valid, the user had around 90 reputation points. All I asked was to fix a confusing situation, on second thought maybe I should have asked the user in a comment instead of flagging. Too late for that now.

Would like to know what happened, why vaporizing the account into thin air? And if the posts can be undeleted it would be fair too.

Comment: Possibly related (don't know for sure): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187251/i-just-lost-all-my-reputation-on-stack-overflow/187252

Comment: I don't have ultra mod powers on SO, but if the account was nuked, there was surely a reason not visible to us unrelated to that post

Comment: @Oded don't think it was sock puppet or using sock puppets, he had many 0 scored posts and some with upvotes, looked totally normal.

Comment: @jmfsg sometimes mistakes happen, we can never know.

Comment: I have access to mod tools on another site, it's not that easy to accidentally nuke a user

Comment: @jmfsg not accident, mistake. Maybe the mod/dev handling the flag didn't notice there are more posts and was thinking it's just a roaming troll.

Comment: You cannot destroy a user from the flag handling section, but never mind, I'll let you get an answer from a SO mod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a little bit of back story to this.

- A community manager had changed that user's name and avatar from those of the [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) account yesterday, and the user changed them back after the community manager asked them in a private message to avoid using the name "Community" in conjunction with the same avatar.
- A moderator handled your flag for the same thing a day later and sent the user a private message asking them to change their name and avatar.
- A different moderator who had seen both messages go out connected the dots and looked into the user's account.  He found that the account had the same IP and email address as a user that he'd recently suspended for sock puppetry, and that the "impostor Community" account was another sock puppet for that account, so the impostor account (user2541941) was destroyed.

As for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17424823/1288) you flagged, I'm not sure if we need to undelete it.  It wouldn't hurt anything, but I don't know how much it helps either.  `UIPageViewController` is already mentioned in an older answer, so I'm not sure this answer linking to [the second and third Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=UIPageViewController&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) for that class is really needed.

Comment: Remember that Google search result orders are different for everyone.

Comment: Bill, are you sure that user ID -1 is legitimate? I mean, who would be stupid enough to use signed ints as identifiers?

Comment: @Undo They're not going to be that different. Those should be on the first page for anyone looking for examples using that class.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You're right. Now I question who the real impostor is!

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn What happens if you suspend Community?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Pretty stupid of that person if you ask me, he could have used ordinary name and keep the sockery going. Anyway most likely there weren't any outstanding posts from such a person so guess we better leave it at that. :)

Comment: @Undo we should try that. If it breaks, we'll just create a new user with an ID of 0, or one up from -1. Make it better!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd A significant fraction of problem users just aren't the sharpest knives in the drawer.